# Dockers container source code mounting failed in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, docker

I have an issue here when I was trying to build and hook-up my local source code into the Container.  Would appreciate if you could advise.

Here is my Docker file per attached screen shot.

What I am trying to do is basically, I want to create a NodeJs Container and hook-up my local nodejs source code into the Container.   It seems my local source code folder not mounted into the Volume,

Also, worth to mention here. I saw some blogs and it says downgrade the version to Docker version to 1.6 will resolve this issue. It that correct?

Please see the attached Dockerfile as image.

Please help and will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6JNN.png)
[error_message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lborD.png)

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Hi Samuel, actually, when I run the "run" command in command prompt, it returns the GUID. Without any error. But, when I check the running status with this command "docker ps -a" , I saw the status was exited. Again, when I dive in further with the "docker logs", I got the error message was " Express module not found". It seems the npm install not doing the job. Any idea? Please see the screenshots.

Comment: @SamuelToh, I have attached the error message screenshot above. Please advise.Thank you.

Comment: It does sounds related to `npm install` but if it isn't doing things correctly the image build would have failed. I will recommend checking the package.json to make sure express is in the dependency list.

Comment: The docker file looks fine to me but I'm not sure - you never know until you build it.

Comment: I did the build as well and all look fine, and without any error. Very strange!

Comment: check and make sure `"express" : ...` exists in your package.json file.

Comment: Yes, is there. Could it be my run command ? Here is my run command ," docker run -d -p 80:80 -v $(pwd):/var/www -w "var/www" dbdoc/nodejs npm start"

Comment: When building your image you copied everything from current work directory into the container's `/var/www` directory and did a `npm install` in there. Then you are mounting your host's current working directory to the container's `/var/www` directory again. I'm thinking that would override your container's `/var/www` directory with your host's current working directory? So if you host hasn't ran `npm install` then that would be a problem. I would say take away the `-v option` or mount it somewhere else, definitely not `/var/www` of the container.

Comment: Good point! @SamuelToh. I did that before without the "-v", and that was working fine with application up and running. But, my local source code didn't mount to the container. Could you please provide me with the solution, how to mount my local source into the container ?

Comment: I have compiled our conversation into an answer for you. Also included the answer to your latter question. @BitNumbers - if I have helped you resolve your initial problem - will appreciate if you can click on the tick beside my answer to mark this as answered. Happy to help further if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q:** Why is my application in docker container failing with error `Cannot find module 'express'`?

**A:** As highlighted in the comment - it is due to the way OP starts his container. Incidentally OP had mapped his current working directory, which is a checkout of his NodeJS application, into the container's `/var/www` directory where he had executed the `npm install` during the image built. And this would have caused the files in the current working directory to override whatever the image has built earlier, also since OP hasn't done a `npm install` in his current working directory therefore it is failing the `express` dependencies not getting installed.

**Q:** Could you please provide me with the solution, how to mount my local source into the container

**A:** As far as I can tell from our comments. You are already doing that. The `-v` options from the `docker` binary allows you to mount the host's file system into the container.

I'm not sure what is your actual use-case here. If you are wanting the container to use its `Node` process to run code from your machine (the host)'s file system then your original command `docker run -d -p 80:80 -v $(pwd):/var/www ...` should do the job. All you need is just run `npm install` on your current working directory. Because whatever you do on your host, the file changes will be reflected onto the container's `/var/www` directory.

Comment: What I understand the benefits having Docker container for Developer, is the Developer can download the source code from the Repo and just mount the local source files to the container. In my case here, what I want to do is, to create a custom Docker container which has all the dependencies installed within the container. If I just run the "node" plain container, it will throw me the same error "Express module not found".

Comment: Also, we don't check-in the node_modules directory into source repo,but the package.json. Refer back to your answer here, that means the developer has to install NPM on the local machine , in -order to run "npm install'? I hope this  make sense. Thank you.

Comment: To me installing `npm` on the machine is a better approach, otherwise u'll end up rebuilding the image whenever dependencies are added or vers updates? Still, I think what u wanted to do is not impossible. U can either `npm install` the deps globally using the `-g` option or do npm install and move the node_module to a directory anywhere other than `/var/www`. Then update the `NODE_PATH` environment variable to point to it. This is so that node knows where to find the dep. And u will still mount the volume like u do.

Comment: For me, I would prefer any developer could have a clean and new machine able to join the development team immediately without installing anything, apart from the IDE. I will spend some time and try to figure out the last approach. FYI, I had tried the -g npm install still no luck. Also, I read some article about the best practices about Docker file, it says better to avoid global installation.

Comment: I see what you meant there. I have no experience doing development work through containers, so I can't comment on it. I usually do my programming task on a local checkout. When I am done coding, I will check in my source code and let the CI do the image build and run the tests in containers etc. To me doing `npm install` is cheap, installing node on my machine, seeing things getting built and seeing how dependencies get pulled allows me to understand how my project is built, and how it all fit together. So there is still a plus point there as well :P

Comment: I got your point :), and nice meeting you. :) . Thank you so much for the effort.

Comment: Nice meeting you too. I see you are from Malaysia. I'm from Singapore but residing in Australia now :o If you think I have helped you in anyway, will appreciate if you can mark this as answered by clicking on the tick beside my answer. Many thanks !